# Read Raid 1 HD as External HD

Tags: hard-drive, raid, data-recovery, raid-1, hard-drive-recovery

I had two drives on a raid 1 but the motherboard literately caught on fire (tis was a brand new comp/board). Comp was rebuild but the drives were not spinning. Change the board on both HDs and they spin. Plug them back in, comp won't booth with them on.

I plugged in one of the HDs via USB to the comp, Disk Management sees it as Not Initialized.

[image]

I could initialized it and then try to use a recovery tool to get the data, but I just feel there should be an easier, or rather safer, way of doing it.

Suggestions please.

Comment: Plug it into another PC - its a common problem that HDDs when put into an enclosure

Comment: What RAID controller were you using? Was it built into the BIOS? (What model?) I suspect Linux dm-raid would recognize it.

Comment: @grawity I started the comp from Ubuntu and it sees the drives as 32GB with one bad sector. Reads both of them the same. They are 2TB drives.

I'm more of a Windows guy, so not sure how to use Linux dm-raid.